# Setting file extensions from uppercase to lowercase in Windows by default

Tags: windows-10, file-extension

I'm wondering if it's possible to set by default the lowercase file extension in Windows 10. When I create a new txt file, the extension is uppercase TXT. How can I set the option lowercase by default?

Comment: What is the reason you want to have the extension in lowercase by default? If you include that through an [edit] people might come up with other methods to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Hello @SaaruLindestøkke it's just for curiosity and for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Alright, oftentimes superuser works best for [practical questions](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask), but your reason is worth mentioning in the question. Then: what have you tried so far? Have you done any websearches? Did you find things but couldn't get them to work? Please [edit] that into your question.

Comment: makes no sense that your text file extensions are uppercase.  These come from the windows registry and dating ALL THE WAY BACK to Windows 95, they are lowercase.  If you look at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt` there in the key name itself is where your case comes from.  You will see a `ShellNew` key that tells the explorer to put it on the `New` menu.  On my machine (and every machine I have ever known),  I get "New Text Document.txt" (I just did it).  Take a look at your registry key case.

Comment: Hello @SeñorCMasMas please see my comment below. I need to rename the registry folder from .txT1 to .txt

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is when you create a txt file from the **New** menu only then do this :

- Open **regedit**
- Open **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT**
- look for **.txt** or **.TXT** ( in your case i think it's going to be **.TXT** )
- right click on it and rename it to something like **.TXT1**
- right click on it again and rename it to **.txt**

if you tried to rename it directly to **.txt** it will not change

if by mistake you deleted the .txt key :

- open notepad
- copy past this

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
"Content Type"="text/plain"
"PerceivedType"="text"
@="txtfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]
"ItemName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,6e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,\
  2d,00,34,00,37,00,30,00,00,00
"NullFile"=""
```

- save as **txt.reg**
- click on it and click yes
  if nothing change delete **.txT1** or **.TXT** key you found, and click the reg file you created **txt.reg**

Comment: Hello @guest777 I changed the name to .TXT1, but then I cannot rename to .txt because I got the error: cannot rename .TXT1. Specified key name already exists. Type another name and try again...I then renamed it with .tx, then .txt (doesn't work), then .txT (doesn't work), then .txT1 it works. The strange thing is that now when I create a new file the extension is .txt, not .txT1

Comment: AHH!!  Don't worry about it then.  You can either delete the .txT1 key or simply leave it.  You are done!  Windows (or regedit) automatically re-created the .txt key.  You might look at both keys to see if it got it all.

Comment: Before deleting anything do a back up by exporting the .txtT1 or any .txt key just in case and you can edit the reg file with notepad to change any .txT1 to .txt in it after that delete the .txt key and .txT1 key in regedit  and after that click on the backup you made it will add the .txt key as it's supposed to be